# Why does skips the "if stack not empty" conditional, when the stack still has elements?

Tags: c++, stack, backtracking

I'm trying to make a program to solve the eight queens problem, however it keeps reaching the last return, when it should not, and tried putting it on an else, but then it never reached it, even if i initially give it an empty stack.
Also for whatever reasons the first time i call the top() function, it return a different element than the last i added, but if i call it again it return the correct element.
So i would like to know where the problem is?

```
bool search(stack<nodo>& board, int n) {
    nodo queen;
    queen=board.top();
    queen=board.top();
    if (queen.y == n)
        return true;

    bool valid;
    if (!board.empty()) {
        queen.y += 1;
        for(int i; i<=n; i++) {
            queen.x = i;
            valid = isvalid(queen,board);
            if (valid) {
                board.push(queen);
                search(board,n);
            }
        }
        board.pop();
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Did you perhaps mean `return search(board, n);` instead of just `search(board, n);`?

Answer (score 3):

use `while` not `if`

```
while(!board.empty()) {

    queen.y += 1;
    for(int i; i<=n; i++){
        queen.x = i;
        valid = isvalid(queen,board);

        if (valid) {

            board.push(queen);
            search(board,n);
        }

    }

    board.pop();
}
```

`if` means check for one time only , but `while` mean do the samething till `board.empty() == true`.

Comment: Ok, i see where the problem, apparently i'm going to have change some things, thanks.